# Colorbox breaking <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox.js for the first time and am having issues with placing a newsletter signup  inside of the popup. I am assigning colorbox to my element .newsletter-popup and it is working correctly, however as mentioned the `<form>` within does not work. I have tested the form and it works correctly when not loading via colorbox?

Also, in the source code of my page I can see some automatically generated colorbox code `#cboxOverlay` and `#colorbox`, why do these appear when I've already assigned colorbox to my own element? I'm also not able to set options for colorbox on my element, as they don't work. Have a got this setup incorrectly?

Working Example (Appears after 3 seconds): http://development.ozonecoffee.co.uk/our-journal/

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery('.newsletter-popup').colorbox({
        trapFocus: false,
        closeButton: true,
        onComplete: function(){ $("#email").focus(); }
    });
}, 3000);

// Close button
$( ".close-popup" ).click(function() {
    $.colorbox.remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="newsletter-popup">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="close-popup"><span>X</span></div>
            <div class="container">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <form class="mailing-list-signup" id="subscribe-form" action="http://ozonecoffee.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=93b92e23751a1d94fe6e57dc9&amp;id=3caae1521b" method="get">
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Sign up for our newsletter" value="" name="EMAIL" >
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="subscribe" >
                </form>         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This looks unrelated to `Colorbox`. In the working example, they are preventing the form from submitting and using the custom function `isValidEmail()`. If successful, it attempts to submit the form using the custom function `submitSubscribeForm()`. If you are using the same methods, we'll need the code for both functions to help you.

Comment: Hi @Daerik - I think it is related to colorbox, as if I load the div .newsletter-popup without colourbox i.e as a standard <div>, everything works perfectly?

Comment: The `<form/>` element will behave naturally unless prevented by JavaScript. It would not matter if it were cloned or moved. From what I've seen in the `Colorbox` documentation, it does not prevent forms from submitting. It's simply a jQuery lightbox. As for the custom functions that we know ARE preventing the form from submitting, you'll need to debug why they are not working properly. If they are functioning prior to loading the lightbox, you may have an issue with the scope. Again, I can't help you further without all your code.

Comment: Hi @Daerik - thank you. What additional code would you need? The markup and JS being used is above. Perhaps the first thing to try and solve is why colorbox is adding additional colorbox elements to the bottom of my source code, despite me assigning it to one of my elements? Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Typically a lightbox would clone your HTML elements to stick it in it's own wrapper. This is to prevent your container from hindering the lightbox. Sometimes they allow you to create your own parent element, but I'm not seeing this plugin supports that. Please reference http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ for more information.